# WebServer plugin file

Tags: linux, http, rhel6, websphere

We have 6 servers under load balancer with 2 member cluster. I want to know if plugin-cfg.xml is used for servers on which httpd process is not running.

The reason I am asking is I suspect on some of the servers plugin-cfg.xml is wrong. However, my infra team tells me that since web server (httpd) is not running on those servers, it does not matter.

We are troubleshooting an issue and want to confirm that if this can be still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

`plugin-cfg.xml` is only used by the WebSphere plugin (something like was_ap20_module) in the web server. If no such web server is running on a particular machine, the plugin file cannot be used on that particular machine.

Now if the `plugin-cfg.xml` on machines that **are** running the plugin has references to those other machines in it, that **would** cause problems.